# how to change the box height of an equation

Tags: boxes

Here is a simple equation `$$ \int_a^b f(x) \, dx $$` how do I calculate the box height?  How do I round to the nearest multiple of `12pt` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `\settoheight` and `\settodepth` macros, which take two arguments, to measure the height above and depth below the baseline. For Computer Modern fonts and a basic document font size of 10pt, the total heights of the integral formulas work out to be 25.1pt and `14.0pt` for display style and text style, respectively.

To force the heights of the formulas to either `24pt` (in the display style case) or `12pt` (in the text style case), you could use a `\resizebox*` directive. Note: don't use `\resizebox`, use `\resizebox*`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\newlength\bxheight
\newlength\bxdepth
\newlength\bxtot
\newcommand\myint{\int_a^b f(x)\,dx} % store the formula (it gets used a lot)
\usepackage{graphicx} % for \resizebox macro
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for \text macro
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\settoheight{\bxheight}{$\displaystyle\myint$}
\settodepth{\bxdepth}{$\displaystyle\myint$}
\setlength\bxtot{\dimexpr\bxheight+\bxdepth\relax}
$\displaystyle\myint$ has height \the\bxheight, depth \the\bxdepth, and total height \the\bxtot.

\medskip
\settoheight{\bxheight}{$\myint$}
\settodepth{\bxdepth}{$\myint$}
\setlength\bxtot{\dimexpr\bxheight+\bxdepth\relax}
$\myint$ has height \the\bxheight, depth \the\bxdepth, and total height \the\bxtot.

\[
\begin{array}{@{}lcc@{}}
& \text{natural size} & \text{rounded to nearest } \\
& & \text{multiple of 12pt} \\
\midrule
\text{display style} & \displaystyle\myint & \resizebox*{!}{24pt}{$\displaystyle\myint$} \\[3ex]
\text{text style}    & \myint              & \resizebox*{!}{12pt}{$\myint$}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to typeset the equation only once in an `\hbox` and use  height of the box `\the\ht` to measure the height of equation (instead of using `\settoheight`)? When I try that, I get `\hbox` height & depth is 0pt.

Comment: @reportaman - I'm not sure I understand the gist (or purpose) of your comment. For sure, the instruction `\newcommand\myint{\int_a^b f(x)\,dx}` ends up (eventually...) placing `\int_a^b f(x)\,dx` in an `\hbox`. Executing the three instructions `\settoheight{\bxheight}{$\myint$} \settodepth{\bxdepth}{$\myint$} \setlength\bxtot{\dimexpr\bxheight+\bxdepth\relax}` as a single instruction, say via `\def\docalcs{\settoheight{\bxheight}{$\myint$} \settodepth{\bxdepth}{$\myint$} \setlength\bxtot{\dimexpr\bxheight+\bxdepth\relax}}`, is straightforward. Please let me know if I missed something.

Comment: I was looking it from the point of efficiency. If a math equation is put in a `\hbox` first, and tex builds that `\hbox` (upon executing `\setbox`) & if  we can query its height & depth then the equation need not be "built" three times by tex... I used the term typeset instead of built.

Comment: @reportaman - I definitely wrote this answer as a one-off project. Economy (terseness?) was not an objective. Feel free to post a new answer that creates the same output but consumes fewer computing cycles.